# Finding PBE in incomplete game

Tags: game-theory

Taxpayers may either have a high income or low income, and they may be either opportunistic or honest.

The tax collector cannot observe any of these characteristics, but after receiving a report from the taxpayer, it may choose to conduct an audit (at cost c) to determine the taxpayer's income.

To simplify, assume low income taxpayers have no income, and high income taxpayers have income equal to 1. High income taxpayers owe a tax t, where 0 < t < 1, while low income taxpayers
owe 0. Honest taxpayers report their true income while opportunistic taxpayers are optimizers who report an income level (0 or 1) that maximizes net (after tax and penalties) income.

The ex-ante probability a tax payer has high income is p, and independently, the probability that a taxpayer is honest is q. If the tax collector audits and finds the taxpayer underreported their income, the taxpayer is fined a predetermined penalty f in [0, 1] in addition to any tax due.

The tax collector's payoff is equal to expected revenue including any penalties) minus audit costs.
(a) Draw the extensive form for this game (don't forget Nature's move).

> (b) Compute a perfect Bayesian equilibrium for this game. How does the equilibrium
> vary with f, t, c, p, q.

> (c) Suppose the tax collector is considering changing the penalty f to maximize expected tax revenue (keeping all other parameters fixed). What f should they choose (f cannot exceed 1 - t)?

————————

I understand the part (a). I could not solve for the part (b) and part (c). Please help me to do these two parts as well. All helps will be appreciated. Many thanks!

---

**According to answers and comments, I solved this question in the following way;**

I don't know whether my solution for part b is true or not. I did this according to the answers. Please make a comment on my solution. And I could not do the part c.

**Last Edit**
[image]

The transformed tree is as follows:

[image]

**I tried to solve the part b with the help of user @VARulle**

First, I define the belief $\mu$ for the information set of TC for low-report.

TC's optimal strategy is

$$EU_{TC}(A|\mu)=\mu(t+f-c)+(1-\mu)(-c)= \mu(t+f) -c $$

$$EU_{TC}(NA|\mu)=\mu(0)+(1-\mu)(0)= 0$$

So, we have three cases

(i) $\sigma_{TC}(A)=1$ if $\mu(t+f) -c >0$ or, $\mu(t+f) >c $

(ii) $\sigma_{TC}(NA)=1$ if $\mu(t+f) -c <0$ or, $\mu(t+f) <c $

(iii) $\sigma_{TC}(A)\in (0, 1)$ and $\sigma_{TC}(NA)\in (0, 1)$ if $\mu(t+f) -c =0$ or, $\mu(t+f) =c $

Let's look at the Tax-payer's optimal strategy (TP)

**Case i:**  $\sigma_{TC}(A)=1$ if $\mu(t+f) -c >0$ or, $\mu(t+f) >c $

For the type of dishonest, High income (DH);

$$U_{TP}^{DH}(RL, A)=1-t-f$$

$$U_{TP}^{DH}(RH, NA)=1-t$$

since $(1-t) > (1-t-f)$, $\sigma_{TP}^{DH}(RH)=1$

so, this type of TP deviates! So, there is no PBE for this case.

**Case ii:**  $\sigma_{TC}(NA)=1$ if $\mu(t+f) -c <0$ or, $\mu(t+f) <c $

For the type of dishonest, High income (DH);

$$U_{TP}^{DH}(RL, NA)=1$$

$$U_{TP}^{DH}(RH, NA)=1-t$$

Then, $\sigma_{TP}^{DH}(RL)=1$

$$\mu = \frac{(1-q)*p*1}{(1-q)*p*1+ (1-q)*(1-p)*0}=1$$

So, $\{(RL, NA), \mu =1, c>(t+f)\}$ is pure Strategy PBE.

**Case iii:**  $\sigma_{TC}(NA)\in (0, 1)$ and $\sigma_{TC}(A)\in (0, 1)$  if  $\mu(t+f) = c $

$$U_{TP}^{DH}(RL)=\sigma_{TC}(NA)*1 +\sigma_{TC}(A)*(1+t-f)=1+(t-f)\sigma_{TC}(A)$$

$$U_{TP}^{DH}(RH)=1-t$$

we have 2 sub-cases

Subcase-1: $1+(t-f)\sigma_{TC}(A) \ge 1-t$ Then, $\sigma_{TP}^{DH}(RL)=1$

Subcase-2: $1+(t-f)\sigma_{TC}(A) \le 1-t$ Then, $\sigma_{TP}^{DH}(RH)=1$

Let's continue with **Subcase-1**

$\sigma_{TC}(A) \ge -t/(t-f)$

$\sigma_{TP}^{DH}(RL)=1$

Then, $\mu =1$

Then, Mixed strategy PBE = $\{ (RL, \sigma_{TC}(A) \in [-t/(t-f), 1]), \mu = 1, c=t+f \}$

Let's start with **Subcase-2**

$\sigma_{TC}(A) \le -t/(t-f)$

$\sigma_{TP}^{DH}(RH)=1$

Then, $\mu =0$ which implies $\mu (t+f)=c \to c=0$. But, $c>0$

So, this case is not possible.

As a result, there are one Mixed Strategy PBE and one pure strategy PBE.

Comment: I don't understand the game tree. Honest or dishonest and high or low income are independent decisions of nature, so there should be 4 different types of TP, right?

Comment: Yes you are right! But, I eliminate the dishonest with low income agents. Since the question says, honest agents always report true, I only consider the honest taxpayer with low income report low income (LR) and the honest tax payer with high income report ( HR). That is, I reduced the types @VARulle

Comment: How do you solve such a question? Can you please show your solution? This question is very important for me to understand because I am preparing an important exam. Many thanks @VARulle

Comment: The last edit is correct (except that N should be NA). You could further simplify the tree by noting that the 2 rightmost branches have identical terminal nodes, so they could be collapsed to a single branch labelled "low income", followed by "Report low" and the TC's final decision.

Comment: After that, first check the case where $c>t+f$. You will see that then auditing is prohibitively costly and the only NE is (RL, NA). The more interesting case is $c<t+f$. There is no pure-strategy NE in this case, but a completely mixed one. You should be able to calculate it by writing down the usual indifference conditions, which is a bit messy because of the many parameters involved. (I haven't done it myself.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your checking my attempts. I added the expression of pure strategy PBE. And also, I tried to do the mixed strategy PBE. (I hope I am in a correct way). What do you think? @VARulle

Comment: Dear @VARulle I also did the mixed strategy in the case-iii. I hope it is correct? And what is your suggestion for the solution of part c? I will be happy if you inform me. Many thanks:)

Comment: Cases i and ii look good, but in case iii, the factor $(1+t-f)$ should be $(1-t-f)$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a) Without loss of generality, assume that every poor is honest. Indeed, form the perspective of the collector, the expected utility of Auditing given that someone is poor and honest or poor and dishonest is the same.

The tree takes the following form:

[image]

b) First, It's clear that everytime a rich reports 1, the tax collector won't audit. If the rich reports 0, the Bayesian belief of the tax collector that he has high income given that he reported 0 is:

$\sigma(p,q) = Pr(H|0) = \frac{Pr(0|H)Pr(H)}{Pr(0|H)Pr(H) + Pr(0|\bar H)Pr(\bar H)} = \frac{p(1-q)}{p(1-q) + 1-p}$

Hence the collector audits if and only if

$E(U(A|0)) > E(U(T|0)) \iff (t+f-c)\sigma(p,q) -c(1-\sigma(p,q)) \geq 0$

Thus iff $ \sigma(p,q) \geq c/(t+f)$, she audits when she receives a 0 report.

The PBEa are thus $[0,-c],[1-t,t-c],[1-t,t-c]$ if $\sigma(p,q) \geq c/(t+f)$ and  $[0,0],[1-t,t],[1,0]$ if $\sigma(p,q) < c/(t+f)$

c) $t+f = 1$ maximizes the tax revenue (has no economic sense, but I can't find out any mixed strategy that solves this paradox...)

Comment: The TC's payoff in the rightmost outcome is $t$, not $0$. Also, the information sets are missing.

Comment: Yeah I copy pasted and deleted the information sets on the Tablet. Later I'll update. I was in a hurry. BTW, for the information set, you simply draw a dashed line below P, HB and HD.

Comment: No, there are two different information sets for the TC, since he observes the report before deciding whether or not to audit.

Comment: @MatteoBulgarelli I solved this part -b according to the answers and comments. What do you think?

Comment: I solved this part -b according to the answers and comments. What do you think?  @VARulle

Comment: I would brutally answer as I did, with no fantasy at all. But I might be wrong!

Comment: This information set makes no sense. It includes the decision nodes of nature (!?) and of the TP. Instead, TC should have two information sets, one including the nodes after observing a 0 report and one including the nodes after observing a 1 report.

Comment: I guess this is very complicated question. At first, really thank you for your great efforts! :)

Comment: Dear @VARulle if it is possible, can you please show your solution? Because i am preparing an important exam and I really need to understand this question. I will be really glad

Comment: Dear @MatteoBulgarelli I am really glad for your great effort and help. Many thanks:)

Comment: @studentp, I haven't found the time to solve the game, I can just see that all the suggested game trees are wrong. But this should be the easy part. The only relevant TP-decision is whether to report high or low in the case that he is opportunistic and rich. And the only relevant TC-decision is whether or not to audit, given that low is reported. All other decisions are either fixed (poor reports low, independently of whether honest or opportunistic, and honest rich reports high by definition) or trivial (TC never audits a high report).

Comment: @VARulle I re-draw the tree according to your comment. And I added this new tree in the question part as a last edit. Please take a look. What do you think? At least, please help me to do this question by your comments. Thank you.

Comment: @studentp Still wrong. All reports are either "Report High" or "Report Low", don't switch to "true" in the right half. Next, delete the A action on the TC's leftmost node: A high report will never be audited, so this branch can be reduced to lead directly to the NA terminal node. Then: the TC's information set connects only the nodes between which he cannot distinguish, i.e. the 3 nodes after receiving a low report. (Strictly speaking there is also an information set connecting the 2 nodes after receiving a high report, but this can be ignored since there is no decision to be made there.)

Comment: @VARulle thank you for your correction. I corrected my mistakes and I re-draw it and post it as the last edit in the question part. Please take a look. I am really happy for your help:) This is so important for me.

Comment: @studentp I'll continue under the question, since this here should be comments to Matteo's answer...

Comment: @VARulle 1) Be polite. I don't know who you are, but please, say "it doesn't make sense to me", or rephrase. I am not your son or your student.

2) It does make sense. It simply conveys the idea that nature and the reporters share the same information, whereas the TC does not have access to such information. However, I should have just included the $P, HB, HD$ nodes in the same set, without the Nature, since also the TC knows the probabilities.

You don't need to make two sets.

Comment: I'm sorry for my blunt language. To rephrase: Your red "information set" is wrong. It is not an information set at all. By definition, an information set is a subset of the decision nodes of a single player, and each decision node included necessarily has to branch out into the same moves. Your red set violates both these conditions, and if it "just included the P, HB, HD nodes", as you now seem to suggest, then it would still violate the second condition. (And it's not about who "knows the probabilities", since these are common knowledge anyway.)

Answer (score 4):

These are the errors in the original diagram:

1. Your game tree does not show the opportunistic-type tax payer's income-reporting choices. They choose between reporting an income of 0 or 1 (you need two extra tax-payer decision nodes and four extra branches at the bottom of the tree). You appear to have assumed that high-income opportunistic tax payers always report low income. It may be they want to report truthfully. If the probability of audit is sufficiently high, then they will report truthfully. Otherwise they will under-report.
2. Also, you appear to have assumed low-income opportunistic tax payers report low income (optimally they will, but the decision should be shown in the tree) and are always taxed $t$ (the same amount as for high income) and fined if audited. There should be no fine for under-reporting and there should be no tax for a low-income opportunistic tax payer (who reports truthfully).
3. You should have dashed lines between all tax-collector decision nodes where the same income is reported (rather than between all nodes where the tax payer has the same income).

The top part of the tree (for the honest tax payer) appears to be correct.

Below is the corrected tree. Note I have not drawn the decision of the opportunistic taxpayer with low income as they optimally choose not to report regardless of the tax collector's choices. Note also that for nature you could have just one decision node with four branches.

[image]

Comment: Dear @smcc thank you for your help. I see how to draw the tree. I tried to solve it, but I could not do. I am preparing an exam, can you please help me to solve for the part b and c. I will be really glad. Many thanks:)

Comment: It needs to be done from the top to the bottom, otherwise it has no sense. Where are the stages of the game, here ?

Comment: In the tree, two natures are used. What you mean? That’s I need to start with assign beliefs in the nodes $(\mu_1, \mu_2, 1-\mu_1-\mu_2)$ and $(\beta, 1-\beta)$ and then I will calculate the ecpected payoffs of Tax collector(TC) @MatteoBulgarelli

Comment: You can remove the branch where the poor are dishonest.

Comment: Additionally, when the collector discovers the dishonest, she earns $t + f - c$, not just $f -c$.

Comment: Yes, it should be $t+f-c$. 

In response to the previous comments: 

Yes, the game tree could have been labelled better (the first node is the move of nature "N" between the words "Honest " and "Opportunistic"). I could also have consolidated the two moves of nature into one.

The branch where the low income opportunistic tax payer is dishonest has not been drawn (i.e. has already been removed as suggested).

Comment: I solved this part -b according to the answers and comments. What do you think? @smcc