# Strict preference relation implies weak preference relation

Tags: microeconomics, preferences, self-study

Condition A:

Given x, y in X such that $yRx$ then it follows that

$\lambda y +(1-\lambda)xRx$ for all $0< \lambda<1$

Condition B:

Given x, y in X such that $yPx$ then it follows that

$\lambda y +(1-\lambda)xPx$ for all $0< \lambda<1$

Show that the condition B implies the condition A.

R refers a weak preference relation and P is a strict preference relation.

---

I don’t understand how to show this implication.

What do you think? How can I show this? I am very confused.

This question is duplicated. I also asked on math-stack exchange website. But there, I could not get any proper answer. What do you think about my question? Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Condition B does not imply condition A. Consider an example of the preference relation defined on $\mathbb{R}$ that is represented by the following utility function:
\begin{eqnarray*} u(x)= \begin{cases} 0 &\text{if } x = 0 \\ 1  & \text{if } x \neq 0\end{cases}\end{eqnarray*}
The preference relation $R$ represented by $u$ satisfies condition B but not condition A.

Comment: Thank you so much professor :)

Comment: The above statement, in my humble view, is not true. The above utility function also satisfies condition A. Indeed, If $u(x'') > u(x')$,  which can hold if and only if $x' = 0$, you necessarily have that $u(\lambda x'' +(1-\lambda)x') > u(x')$, which implies condition A as well.
Since in any example where you have a strict preference in the above example you need $x=0$, I don't think that the above statement is correct.
A strict preference relation always implies a weak preference relation, if preferences are rational.

Comment: It does not satisfy condition A because $1 R (-1)$, but for $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$ we get $\neg 0 R (-1)$.

Comment: EDIT: a strict preference relation always implies a weak preference relation, by definition.

Comment: Ah, ok, you're considering also the negatives. Note, however, that you just assumed that you can represent this preference relation with an utility function, which is not in the text.

Answer (score 1):

By definition $y \succ x$ *means* that $y \succeq x$ *but not* $x \succeq y$

Thus if $y \succ x$, then $y \succeq x$, which is the first part of the two conditions. If $y \succ x$  implies (for some random reason) that for *any* $\lambda\in(0,1)$, you have that $ \lambda y + (1-\lambda)x \succ x$, then, by definition of $\succ$, we have that $\lambda y + (1-\lambda)x \succeq x $  *but not* $x \succeq \lambda y + (1-\lambda)x$. Read the proof again: I just showed that any time condition B is true, thus any time that $y \succ x$ and, for some random reason, for any $\lambda \in (0,1)$, $ \lambda y + (1-\lambda)x \succ x$, then condition A is also true.

Note that: 1) the problem doesn't state that $\succeq$ is rational (necessary but not sufficient condition for $\succeq$ to be represented by an utility function), 2) the problem doesn't state that $\succeq$ can be represented by an utility function.

Comment: Many many thanks.

Comment: Dear Matreo I have a question on PBE. Someone draw the extensive form game tree but I could not solve it. Can you please help me to do part (b) (c) ? https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/52557/finding-pbe-in-incomplete-game

Comment: I'll try tonight, I need to work, sorry, but I promise I'll have a look.

Comment: I see, I will be very happy. Many thanks:)