# Finding cost function

Tags: self-study, optimization, profit-maximization, cost-functions

The production function is as follows

$$f(z)=(z_1+z_2)(z_3+z_4)$$

Find the cost function?

What I did is as follows. But I am not sure about my solution. How do you solve it?

[image]

[image]

*duplicated question

Comment: Cost function you got is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much @Amit

Comment: @Amit can you please look at my question? This question is very important for my exam. I really need to understand it. But I could not solve for part (b) and (c). You provide very good solutions. I will be really happy if you show your solution. Thanks a lot! https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/52557/finding-pbe-in-incomplete-game